# Where do the values in a p:datatable for the currentPageReportTemplate come from?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I am trying to find out how the `currentPageReportTemplate` attribute of the `dataTable` tag and the resolving of its values works. I found e.g. this:

```
<p:dataTable currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} von {totalRecords}">
```

There are some keywords which primefaces seems to replace with values, but where does it get the values from and how do I know what keywords are available?
The contents of the dataTable I am given are backed with an extension of `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel`, which overrides the load method to provide the content for the table rows. But I cant manage to find out where the data for `totalRecords` of the `currentPageReportTemplate` comes from.

I did some research, but could not find any kind of documentation that satisfied me. I read e.g. the tag api documentation: https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/dataTable.html

But there is just one little sentence about the `currentPageReportTemplate` attribute:

> Template of the currentPageReport UI.

I also found this page https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml with an example, but no explanation on how the values (e.g. for `totalRecords`) are determined.
How does Primefaces determine the value for e.g. `totalRecords` in the dataTable?

Comment: It takes it from the value that backs the setTotalRowCount in your class that implements the LazyDataModel, which you should set